# Can't get jQuery UI modal dialog to be modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can't get a jQuery UI *modal* dialog it to work as in the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)! Consider this recipe:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>First open a modal <a href="" onclick="$('<div>something</div>').dialog({modal: true}); return false;"> dialog</a></p>
    <p>Then try to hover over <a href="broken"> me</a></p>
    <p>And <a onclick="alert('clicked!'); return false;" href="alsobroken"> click me!</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

While the dialog is active, the second link is correctly disabled but the third link (onclick) still works! Also, the little browser hand appears when hovering both links. This is not like the demo... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117697/cant-get-jquery-ui-modal-dialog-to-be-modal/4117973#4117973) points out, this is normally controlled by the jQueryUI CSS. But one can get around it by adding slightly hackish snippet to one's CSS file.

```
.ui-widget-overlay { 
    height:100%; 
    left:0; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
 }
```

That way the "shroud" div covers up all buttons and there's no need to use the jQueryUI CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not including the jQuery UI CSS file(s).  You get the CSS file from the download package you prepare at the jQuery UI site, or I think you can get the standard "lightness" one from Google. Without the CSS file, the mechanism can't make the "shroud" layer work.  Also you may have noticed that the dialog doesn't look like anything; that'll get better too when you add the CSS files.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxyBG/1/

Comment: I would rather not include the jQueryUI CSS. Can you help me find which CSS property has to be set on which CSS class so that the "shroud" layer works? Also, I did notice that the dialog doesn't look like anything, in my real app I have CSS in place that takes care of that, this was just a simple recipe.

Comment: Well, I sympathize with you here, but the jQuery UI widgets **heavily** depend on that CSS.  There's so much CSS dependence there, in fact, that it might be easier to find a different dialog tool. Or, you can get their CSS and then edit it however you want. It's sort-of messy, but they did use good class names so you can figure out what's what. I've done that in my own application, because I also did not like the "look" of jQuery UI stuff.

Comment: Well I did find it, just add .ui-widget-overlay {
height:100%;
left:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
} This makes the shroud layer cover everything else. Thanks for your "jsfiddle" link, it's a superb tool for these kinds of experiments! So to summarize: either include the jQuery UI CSS or use the above hack, if you also add this info to your answer I will accept it :-)